# How to pass multiple template files to user_Data variable in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-template-file

assign multiple templates files to user_Data variable. 
we dont want to merge this template in single file due to some architectural pattern .

I'm new to terraform so struggling on this.

```
data "template_file" "userdata_lin1" {
  template = <<EOF
#!/bin/bash
crontab cronjobfileremote
EOF
}

data "template_file" "userdata_lin2" {
  template = <<EOF
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello"
EOF
}

 user_data  = "${data.template_file.user_data1.rendered}"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a fundamental constraint of most cloud platforms that "user data" or "custom metadata" etc (terminology varies by vendor) is a single opaque string of bytes. The interpretation of those bytes depends on what software you have installed in your virtual machine image that makes use of it.

A common choice of such software is `cloud-init`. If you are using `cloud-init` then the "user data" can be provided in [a number of different formats](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/format.html).

The main way to provide multiple distinct sections to `cloud-init` is via [a MIME-Multipart archive](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/format.html#mime-multi-part-archive), which is a concatenation of several values interspersed with headers to allow cloud-init to identify the boundaries and understand how you intend each part to be interpreted.

Because `cloud-init` is a very common choice of software for interpreting "user data", Terraform has [a `cloudinit` provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/cloudinit/) which includes [a data source for constructing a MIME-Multipart archive](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/cloudinit/d/cloudinit_config.html).

```
data "cloudinit_config" "example" {
  gzip          = false
  base64_encode = false

  part {
    content_type = "text/x-shellscript"
    filename = "userdata_lin1"
    content  = <<-EOF
      #!/bin/bash
      crontab cronjobfileremote
    EOT
  }

  part {
    content_type = "text/x-shellscript"
    filename = "userdata_lin2"
    content  = <<-EOF
      #!/bin/bash
      echo "hello"
    EOT
  }
}
```

You can then set your `user_data` argument to the output from this data source:

```
  user_data = data.cloudinit_config.example.rendered
```

It's important to note that from the perspective of Terraform and from your cloud compute provider, the content of `user_data` is just an arbitrary string. Any issues in processing the string must be debugged within the target operating system itself, by reading the `cloud-init` logs to see how it interpreted the configuration and what happened when it tried to take those actions.

Comment: martin could u also take a look at this question . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62101009/terraform-copy-upload-files-to-aws-ec2-instance

Answer (score 5):

What I've done in the past is to combine two template files in one.
Like this:

```
data "template_file" "userdata" {
  template = "${format("%s%s", file("${path.module}/../common.sh"), file("${path.module}/fo.sh"))}"

  vars {
    efs_url     = "${var.efs_url}"
    hostname    = "${data.template_file.hostname.rendered}"
    api_key     = "${var.api_key}"
  }
}
```

As you can see I'm combining two template files:

- `../common.sh`
- `fo.sh`

In my case, this was part of a project with multiple terraform modules `common.sh` was in the parent folder and contained everything that was needed for all the child modules, then each module added it's own specific requirements.

You can also see that one of the variables for interpolation is also a template_file:
`hostname    = "${data.template_file.hostname.rendered}"`
That is perfectly fine and helps nesting templates. Just in case if you need it...

Comment: thank you Helder for your response . Martin answer solved my issue but this is new tip i learned from your answer . so thank you for that.could u also help me on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62101009/terraform-copy-upload-files-to-aws-ec2-instance

Comment: @pratik I learned something too I never seen that `cloudinit_config` before