# terraform copy/upload files to aws ec2 instance

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-template-file

We have cronjob and shell script which we want to copy or upload to aws ec2 instance while creating instance using terraform.

we tried

1. file provisioner : 
   but its not wokring , and read this option does not work with all terraform version

```
      provisioner "file" {
        source      = "abc.sh"
        destination = "/home/ec2-user/basic2.sh"
      }
```

2. tried data template file option

```
    data "template_file" "userdata_line" {
      template = <<EOF
    #!/bin/bash
    mkdir /home/ec2-user/files2
    cd /home/ec2-user/files2
    sudo touch basic2.sh
    sudo chmod 777 basic2.sh
    base64 basic.sh |base64 -d >basic2.sh
    EOF
    }
```

tried all option but none of them working.
could u please help or advise .
I am new to terraform so struggling on this from long time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

somehow in corporate domain none of the options worked.
but finally we were able to copy /download files using s3 bucket.

create s3.tf to upload this files basic2.sh

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "demo-s3" {

  bucket = "acom-demo-s3i-<bucketID>-us-east-1"
  acl    = "private"


  tags {
    Name = "acom-demo-s3i-<bucketID>-us-east-1"
    StackId = "demo-s3"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "s3_policy" {

  bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.demo-s3.id}"

  policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2009-10-17",
    "Statement": [
            {
            "Sid": "Only allow specific role",
            "Effect": "allow",
            "Principal":{ "AWS": ["arn:aws:iam::<bucketID>:role/demo-s3i"]},
            "Action":  "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
          "arn:aws:s3:::acom-demo-s3i-<bucketID>-us-east-1",
          "arn:aws:s3:::acom-demo-s3i-<bucketID>-us-east-1/*"
            ]

        }
    ]
}
EOF
}


resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "object" {
  bucket = "acom-demo-s3i-<bucketID>-us-east-1"
  key    = "scripts/basic2.sh"
  source = "scripts/basic2.sh"
  etag = "${filemd5("scripts/basic2.sh")}"
}
```

and then declared file download portion in other tpl file.

```
 aws s3 cp s3://acom-demo-s3i-<bucketID>-us-east-1/scripts/basic2.sh /home/ec2-user/basic2.sh
```

Comment: question for me is, is the aws cli available on the instance, without configuring it? e.g. will the aws s3 cp even work without adding aws cli to instance?

Answer (score 49):

When starting from an AMI that has [cloud-init](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/) installed (which is common in many official Linux distri), we can use cloud-init's [`write_files` module](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#write-files) to place arbitrary files into the filesystem, as long as they are small enough to fit within the constraints of the `user_data` argument along with all of the other `cloud-init` data.

As with all cloud-init modules, we configure `write_files` using [cloud-init's YAML-based configuration format](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/format.html#cloud-config-data), which begins with the special marker string `#cloud-config` on a line of its own, followed by a YAML data structure. Because JSON is a subset of YAML, we can use Terraform's [`jsonencode`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/jsonencode.html) to produce a valid value<sup>[1]</sup>.

```
locals {
  cloud_config_config = <<-END
    #cloud-config
    ${jsonencode({
      write_files = [
        {
          path        = "/etc/example.txt"
          permissions = "0644"
          owner       = "root:root"
          encoding    = "b64"
          content     = filebase64("${path.module}/example.txt")
        },
      ]
    })}
  END
}
```

The `write_files` module can accept data in base64 format when we set `encoding = "b64"`, so we use that in conjunction with Terraform's [`filebase64`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/filebase64.html) function to include the contents of an external file. Other approaches are possible here, such as producing a string dynamically using Terraform templates and using [`base64encode`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/base64encode.html) to encode it as the file contents.

If you can express everything you want cloud-init to do in a single configuration file like the above then you can assign `local.cloud_config_config` directly as your instance `user_data`, and cloud-config will should recognize and process it on system boot:

```
  user_data = local.cloud_config_config
```

If you instead need to combine creating the file with some other actions, like running a shell script, you can use cloud-init's [multipart archive](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/format.html#mime-multi-part-archive) format to encode multiple "files" for cloud-init to process. Terraform has a `cloudinit` provider that contains a data source for easily constructing a multipart archive for cloud-init:

```
data "cloudinit_config" "examplecfg" {
  gzip          = false
  base64_encode = false

  part {
    content_type = "text/cloud-config"
    filename     = "cloud-config.yaml"
    content      = local.cloud_config_config
  }

  part {
    content_type = "text/x-shellscript"
    filename     = "example.sh"
    content  = <<-EOF
      #!/bin/bash
      echo "Hello World"
    EOF
  }
}
```

This data source will produce a single string at `cloudinit_config.example.rendered` which is a multipart archive suitable for use as `user_data` for cloud-init:

```
  user_data = data.cloudinit_config.examplecfg.rendered
```

EC2 imposes a maximum [user-data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-add-user-data.html) size of 64 kilobytes, so all of the encoded data together must fit within that limit. If you need to place a large file that comes close to or exceeds that limit, it would probably be best to use an intermediate other system to transfer that file, such as having Terraform write the file into an Amazon S3 bucket and having the software in your instance retrieve that data using [instance profile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html) credentials. That shouldn't be necessary for small data files used for system configuration, though.

It's important to note that from the perspective of Terraform and EC2 the content of `user_data` is just an arbitrary string. Any issues in processing the string must be debugged within the target operating system itself, by reading the cloud-init logs to see how it interpreted the configuration and what happened when it tried to take those actions.

---

**[1]**: We could also potentially use [`yamlencode`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/yamlencode.html), but at the time I write this that function has a warning that its exact formatting may change in future Terraform versions, and that's undesirable for `user_data` because it would cause the instance to be replaced. If you are reading this in the future and that warning is no longer present in the `yamldecode` docs, consider using `yamlencode` instead.

Comment: Is it possible to do this but with a Elastic Beanstalk instance? like create a `.env` file there to avoid the 4K environment limit

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not very familiar with Elastic Beanstalk. It seems quite different to other EC2-related deployment options so I'd suggest asking a new question on Stack Exchange so it'll hopefully be more visible to people who are familiar with Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: Hi Martin, I think "user_data = cloudinit_config.example.rendered" should be "user_data = data.cloudinit_config.example.rendered". Or is there a different usage I don't know? Maybe related with terraform version?

Comment: Yes, you're correct Ferhat. I used the syntax for managed resources, but this is a data resource and so needs the `data.` prefix. I'll edit the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @MartinAtkins In what order will these run? Is there a way to specify the order? I'm using your example to pass in a file and also running a user-data script and for my build the order in which those run is important

Comment: I'm afraid I don't recall off the top of my head exactly how cloud-init prioritizes different types of data in the MIME parts. I remember that cloud-init does prioritize some actions over others, but the exact order [is configurable](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/base_config_reference.html#example). The various modules whose names start with `scripts-` are the ones which will interpret the shell script and it seems that by default they all run long after the `write-files` module.

Answer (score 20):

I used `provisioner "file"` just for that, no issues...
but you do have to provide a connection:

```
resource "aws_instance" "foo" {
...
  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "~/foobar"
    destination = "~/foobar"

    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      user        = "ubuntu"
      private_key = "${file("~/Downloads/AWS_keys/test.pem")}"
      host        = "${self.public_dns}"
    }
  }
...
}
```

here are some code examples:
https://github.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/blob/master/TerraForm/ec2_ubuntu.tf#L21

Comment: The problem I run into with this method though is that you cannot use that file in user data, since this occurs after boot.

Comment: @openCivilisation Ye, anything you need present in the OS you should bake into your AMI, look into Packer for that

Answer (score 7):

Here is a bit simpler example how to use `write_files` with `cloud-init` as described by @martin-atkins

Content of the `templates/cloud-init.yml.tpl`

```yaml
#cloud-config
package_update: true
package_upgrade: true

packages:
  - ansible

write_files:
  - content: |
      ${base64encode("${ansible_playbook}")}
    encoding: b64
    owner: root:root
    path: /opt/ansible-playbook.yml
    permissions: '0750'

runcmd:
 - ansible-playbook /opt/ansible-playbook.yml
```

Content of the `main.tf` file:

```
data "template_file" "instance_startup_script" {
  template = file(format("%s/templates/templates/cloud-init.yml.tpl", path.module))

  vars = {
    ansible_playbook = templatefile("${path.module}/templates/ansible-playbook.yml.tpl", {
      playbookvar = var.play_book_var
    })
    
    cloudinitvar = var.cloud_init_var
  }
}
```

It is possible to use variable interpolation for cloud-init and ansible-playbook templates both

Comment: The b64 encoding here helped me out in writing YAML config files via cloud init from a separate file, thx!

Previously I was using the UTF8 encoding for the `:` and but was limited to an inline double-quoted string.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use file provisioner with connection details to the ec2 instance. A sample config would look like this:

```
provisioner "file" {
  source      = "${path.module}/files/script.sh"
  destination = "/tmp/script.sh"

  connection {
    type     = "ssh"
    user     = "root"
    password = "${var.root_password}"
    host     = "${var.host}"
  }
}
```

You can use username / password, private key or even a bastion host to connect. For more details https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/connection.html

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
resource "aws_instance" "myapp-server" {
  ami = data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id
  instance_type = xx
  subnet_id =  xx
  vpc_security_group_ids = xx
  availability_zone=xx
  associate_public_ip_address = true  
  key_name = xx  
  user_data = file(xx)

  connection {
    type     = "ssh"
    host     =  self.public_ip
    user     = "ubuntu"
    private_key     = file(xx) 
  }
 
   provisioner "file" {
    source      = "source-file"
    destination = "dest-file"
  }

}
```